# Compute $A^2 $and $A^3$. What will $A^{2n}$ and $A^{2n+1}$ turn out to be?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A= \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      {1\over2}&{-1\over2}&{-1\over2}&{-1\over2}\\
      {-1\over2}&{1\over2}&{-1\over2}&{-1\over2}\\{-1\over2}&{-1\over2}&{1\over2}&{-1\over2}\\{-1\over2}&{-1\over2}&{-1\over2}&{1\over2}
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Compute $A^2$ and $A^3$. What will $A^{2n}$ and $A^{2n+1}$ turn out to be?

I know the answers because I read them $A^{2n} = I$ and $A^{2n+1} = A$, but I do not know how to get there. Use the algebraic rules and I think I was doing it, but in the end I did not give there. I do not know if you could use matrix math induction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you expand out $A^2$ and $A^3$ as directed?  I think that once you do that, the other question will have an obvious answer.

Comment: Notably, we can write $A = I - 2 xx^T$, where $x = \frac 12 (1,1,1,1)$

Comment: A^2 is the 4×4 identity matrix I, whereas A^3 = A

Comment: Thus A^2n = I for even powers and A^2n+1 = A for odd powers, where n
is a positive integer right?

Answer (score 2):

Did you compute $A^2$ as requested?  By the answer you give, you should have gotten $A^2=I$.  Did you?  If so, can you compute $A^3$?  How about $A^{2n}=(A^2)^n$?

Comment: I'm not sure $A^2$ is actually $I$, since the first row and second column are not orthogonal. Given the problem statement this seems like a typo?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb:  I hadn't checked, but they look orthogonal to me.  The first two products are minus times plus and the last two are minus times minus, giving zero sum.  I just checked and find [$A^2=I$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1,-1,-1,-1),(-1,1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,-1,1))%5E2)

Comment: @ThomasGrubb indeed we have $A^2 = I$. This matrix is a Householder transformation.

Comment: Oh man sorry about that, forgot how to multiply for a second there.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a symmetric matrix given by $-\frac{1}{2}U+I$, where $U$ is a rank-$1$ matrix given by $1$s only.
From $\operatorname{Spec}(U)=\{0,0,0,4\}$ we get $\operatorname{Spec}(A)=\{1,1,1,-1\}$. The spectral theorem then ensures both the sequences $\{A^{2n}\}_{n\geq 0}$ and $\{A^{2n+1}\}_{n\geq 0}$ are constant.